# Search a combination of 3 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search in a MySQL database a combination of three successives values 
Example, here is a table:

```
| id | value  |
| 1  | value0 |
| 2  | value1 |
| 3  | value2 |
| 4  | value3 |
| 5  | value4 |
| 6  | value0 |
| 7  | value1 |
| 8  | value2 |
```

I want to search, how many times there is, in the order a row containing "value0", and next row contains "value1" ans next row contains "value2". In the above data, the result will be 2 as we have twice value0, value1, value2 in three successives rows.

Is it possible with SQL ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: select count(*) from (select value,count(value) from table group by value having count(value) > 2)temp, ,  it is sqlserver code,,,,try the same in mysq ,,

Comment: Above count -1 , , will be your answer, , if my understanding is not wrong, ,,also sorry to gave u the code in mssql, ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this my friend

```
SELECT COUNT( value ) 
FROM test 
WHERE value =  'value0'
AND id +1
IN (

SELECT id
FROM test 
WHERE value =  'value1'
)
AND id +2
IN (

SELECT id
FROM test 
WHERE value =  'value2'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` to first order your rows, then perform an aggregation using `GROUP BY`. Try this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39f70d/1).

```
SELECT myvalue, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY myvalue
ORDER BY myvalue;
```